# I'm trying to automate some Attachmate Extra! with VBA. How do I press Page Down on the reflection?

Tags: excel, vba, extra, attachmate-extra

So I have to automate a task for the company I'm in, and it involves Attachmate Reflection Extra! (.edp)

I've been trying to press the key Page Down with no sucess.
Not with sendcontrolkey, not with "RollUp", not with "PageDown", "PGDN", nothing works.
How can I press PageDown on Attachmate Extra?

```
       strPag = Trim(ExtraEcran1.getstring(13, 2, 8))
            ExtraEcran1.SendKeys "<RollUp>"
        qtdPag = qtdPag + 1

        Do While strPag <> Trim(ExtraEcran1.getstring(13, 2, 8)) And i < 5
            strPag = Trim(ExtraEcran1.getstring(13, 2, 8))
            i = i + 1
            qtdPag = qtdPag + 1
            ExtraEcran1.SendKeys "<PAGEDOWN>"
        Loop
```

This is a recorded macro from Attachmate Extra!, which didn't work for me

```
Dim osCurrentScreen As Screen
Dim osCurrentTerminal As Terminal
Dim returnValue As Integer


Const NEVER_TIME_OUT = 0

Dim ESC As String   ' Chr(rcESC) = Chr(27) = Control-[

Set osCurrentTerminal = ThisFrame.SelectedView.Control
Set osCurrentScreen = osCurrentTerminal.Screen

ESC = Chr(27)

' Press VtNextScreen (Executar a função Próxima tela).
Call osCurrentScreen.SendControlKey(ControlKeyCode_NextScreen)
'Wait for a string on the host screen before continuing
returnValue = osCurrentScreen.WaitForString3(ESC & ">", NEVER_TIME_OUT, WaitForOption.WaitForOption_AllowKeystrokes)
If (returnValue <> ReturnCode_Success) Then
    Err.Raise 11001, "WaitForString3", "Timeout waiting for string.", "VBAHelp.chm", "11001"
End If
```

Also, here are the codes of extra sendkeys
https://docs.attachmate.com/extra/x-treme/apis/com/5250functionkeys_des.htm

[image: I]

Edit: couldn't get it to work in any way. Decide to, instead, go with a lot of down keys.

Comment: Hi, please show the code you are using so that we can try to help you out...

Comment: It is a little long, but here's a snippet:
'            strPag = Trim(ExtraEcran1.getstring(13, 2, 8))
                ExtraEcran1.SendKeys "<RollUp>"
            qtdPag = qtdPag + 1
            
            Do While strPag <> Trim(ExtraEcran1.getstring(13, 11, 10)) And i < 5
                strPag = Trim(ExtraEcran1.getstring(13, 11, 10))
                i = i + 1
                qtdPag = qtdPag + 1
                ExtraEcran1.SendKeys "<PAGEDOWN>"
            Loop'

Comment: I was experimenting a little with it

Comment: Can you edit the question to insert the code and format it appropriately?  Seeing it in a comment makes it unreadable

Comment: Oh sorry about that, there it is

Comment: Added a recorded macro in Attachmate.

Comment: Check the keyboard map to see what is assigned to the Page Down key and try sending that value

Comment: I tried that too: with NumPadPgDn, PgDn, "Teclado numérico 3" and "Próxima Tela", none of those worked.